# Dismissing Bootbox Modal on mouse click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootbox

I am incorporating Bootbox Modal windows into my project and have a question about the functionality.  Is there a way to dismiss the window when the user clicks off of the window (loses focus)?  I read through this link: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html, but I was only able to figure out how to dismiss the window when the user presses the Esc key.  Any ideas?